# Android ProgressDialog setMessage from string Resources

Tags: android, android-resources

I have this code

```
    public void serviceUnavailable() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressBar.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        atsSocketManager.disconnect();
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            progressBar.setCancelable(false);
            progressBar.setTitle(R.string.ats_title_wait);
            progressBar.setMessage(R.string.ats_unavailable_service);
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressBar.show();
        }
    });
}
```

But I am getting an error on line where I am setting the message if I set like this

```
progressBar.setMessage(R.string.ats_unavailable_service);
```

The error is this

> error: no suitable method found for setMessage(int)
>   method ProgressDialog.setMessage(CharSequence) is not applicable
>   (actual argument int cannot be converted to CharSequence by method invocation conversion)
>   method AlertDialog.setMessage(CharSequence) is not applicable
>   (actual argument int cannot be converted to CharSequence by method invocation conversion)

where I set the title is almost the same and is working

```
progressBar.setTitle(R.string.ats_title_wait);
```

If I put the text between comas is working, but I want to understand why this way doesn't work

```
progressBar.setMessage("Service unavailable");
```

thank you

Comment: you have the `context`. `.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.ats_unavailable_service));`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Because `setMessage()` is not designed to get resource string as int.

You have to get String from resource int and apply to `setMessage()` using `getResource().getString()` method of Application Context.

Like,

```
progressBar.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.ats_unavailable_service));
```

Comment: `.getResource()` should change to `.getResources()`

Answer (score 0):

If setMessage() or any other such methods gives you trouble on setting of text from xml resource file, especially with the Context issue, then this approach worked for me with a progress bar:

```
//we initialize the progress bar, get the string from xml, and pass it to setMessage
    final ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(CheckinActivity.this);
    String waitMSG = getString(R.string.please_wait);
    progressBar.setMessage(waitMSG);
```